# Accessing object from inside OnClick(view v)

Tags: android, onclick

I am attempting to create an application in Android.

I have a written a number of classes. The code below is the simplest of them, but it is sufficient to illustrate the problem I have not been able to solve.

```
public class Letter
{
    private char letter;

    public Letter( )
    {
        letter = ' ';
    }

    public void setLetter(char c)
    {
        letter = c;
    }

    public char getLetter( )
    {
        return letter;
    }
}
```

I can define an object of this class with the following code: `L = new Letter( );`

If I want to set the value of letter, I can use the code `L.setLetter(‘a’)`. Similarly, if I want to access this letter I can use the code `L.getLetter( );`

The problem is how to gain access to the letter object from inside `OnClick(view v)`. The situation is further complicated by the fact that I need to perform the set operation on letter with one button and the get operation by another button.

Any help you can provide me will be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Could you provide us a minimal working example ? Have you seen http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html (i guess so...) ? Or http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem I proposed.

```
final Letter M = new Letter();

final New_Button button_Q = new New_Button(this);
button_Q.setText("Q");
button_Q.setId('A');
button_Q.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
         char c = button_Q.getText( ).charAt(0);
         M.setLetter(c);
    }
});
```

Declaring my objects final was the key to developing the solution. Thank you francis for commenting on my code. Any further points you wish to add would be appreciated.